# ANDROID: API 21 Action Bars Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

The old method of doing tabs by using actionBar.setNavigation() is crossed out and crahses on run. Android Studio seems to be suggesting that there is a new way to implement tabs. How!?! And will these new tabs follow the material design tabs?

Comment: since no alternative for action bar tabs in api 21. Instead you can follow up navigation drawer OR action bar option menu.

Comment: @Pravin are you sure that there isn't any alternative for action bar tabs in API 21? I know it's *deprecated* but there should be a workaround. Not sure but you can give a try to [SlidingTabStrip](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabStrip.html)

Comment: I went through [Action Bar] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html) and there url provided in NAVIGATION MODE section is not presenting any alternatives. So I suggested Nav-drawer.. else @PareshMayani Your option is also right and my also nt bad..

Comment: @PareshMayani If i am wrong please correct me.Your words are always welcome.

Comment: @PareshMayani That looks very much to what I'm trying to succeed. Do you know if that is what google is using for their new L Material Apps, like contacts? Since I'm going for Material Design.

Comment: @AlexCarter not sure though but you can check it's implemented! https://plus.google.com/114432517923423045208/posts/Wt9PAMpJ6R5

Comment: @PareshMayani OK I asked how he did it. It's also implemented in official Google L apps like contacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use SlidingTabs with view pagers, video found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRg_eDfQ8fk&channel=androiddevelopers